# How to access remote Linux sever path using Java program on another remote Linux server?

Tags: java, linux, file-io, path

I am new to Linux world.
I have a Java program which is trying to read file on remote Linux server.
When I run the program on my Windows machine I provide remote file path as below
\\Server_18\logs\Software\Accurate1\File_Name.txt

This works perfectly fine when I run my java code on Windows OS.

Now the problem is when I try to run the same program on Linux OS then program is not able to get the file at that location. I am using

```
CommonUtils.isFileExists(\\Server_18\logs\Software\Accurate1\File_Name.txt) //this returns false
```

I think there must be a different way if I need to provide path of a file which is on remote server.
I checked several questions related to this but could not get the exact answer.
Is there anybody who can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the file is on a remote Linux server? When accessing the file from a Linux machine, you probably need the protocol, e.g. "smb://", but also "\" is not the path separator on Linux, it's "/", so the right path might be something like "smb://Server_18/logs/Software/Accurate1/File_Name.txt" to access it from a Linux machine.

Comment: Thanks bsinky can I use this protocol directly in my API as
CommonUtils.isFileExists(smb://Server_18/logs/Software/Accurate1/File_Name.txt)

Comment: Hi bsinky I tried using smb://Server_18/logs/Software/Accurate1/File_Name.txt but it is not working